# Combining results of two CompletableFuture with different return types

Tags: java, completable-future

I have 2 different CompletableFuture that I like to run in parallel (each has a different return type) and then to combine their results:

```
 CompletableFuture<Person> person = personDB.asyncCall(..);
 CompletableFuture<Dog> dog = dogDB.asyncCall(...);
```

Now I like to combine the dog.name & the person name:

```
return dog.getName() + person.getName()
```

I was trying to use

```
  CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(perons, dog);
  combinedFuture.thenApply(aVoid -> {
             // now what?
        });
```

But got suck here.

Answer (score 0):

Use get() method to wait for them to finish.

```
CompletableFuture<Void> combinedFuture = CompletableFuture.allOf(perons, dog);
combinedFuture.get(); // wait for all of them to complete
return dog.getName() + person.getName();
```

See https://www.baeldung.com/java-completablefuture

> Notice that the return type of the CompletableFuture.allOf() is a
>   CompletableFuture. The limitation of this method is that it does
>   not return the combined results of all Futures. Instead you have to
>   manually get results from Futures. Fortunately,
>   CompletableFuture.join() method and Java 8 Streams API makes it
>   simple:

Comment: There is no point of using `allOf()` if it is to call `get()` on it immediately afterwards. Calling `get()` on each individual future does exactly the same, and you are doing it anyway.

Comment: @DidierL I guess it was meant that the author wanted to run two completable futures in parallel and combine responses afterward.

Comment: @privalou my point was that you don’t need the `allOf()` to do that. Just `return dog.join().getName() + person.join().getName()`. (note that the `join()` is missing in this answer btw)

Comment: and am I right that in this case ```person``` and ```dog``` completable futures will be executed immediately and when we will receive results from both futures?